# Implementing split() function in Rcpp

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, rcpp

I am  trying to implement native split function in R in c++ for Vector,Matrix and Data Frame separately.For example the function below serves the purpose of splitting a vector.

```
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;
//[[Rcpp::export]]
List splitVecCpp(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
std::map<double,NumericVector> output;
 for (int i=0;i<x.size();i++) {
        output[ y[i] ].push_back(x[i]);
      }
           return wrap(output);
}
```

But even this is slower than the native split function. I think the push_back function makes the above version slow since it reallocate the vector for each push back. But I am not sure. Any suggestion and explanations are welcome.

Next the Split function for Matrix is as below

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
std::map<double,std::set<int> > uniqueCpp(NumericVector x){
std::map<double,std::set<int> > out; 
for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++){
  if(out.count(x[i])){
    std::set<int> temp_set=out.find(x[i])->second;
    temp_set.insert(i);
    out[x[i]]=temp_set;
  }else{
    std::set<int> temp_set;
    temp_set.insert(i);
    out[x[i]]=temp_set;
  }
}
return out;
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
List splitMatCpp(NumericMatrix splited,NumericVector spliter){
std::map<double,std::set<int> > uniqueSpliter=uniqueCpp(spliter); 
std::map<double,NumericMatrix> output;

for(std::map<double , std::set<int> >::iterator it=uniqueSpliter.begin();it!=uniqueSpliter.end();++it){
  std::set<int> indices=it->second;
  NumericMatrix temp_mat(indices.size(),splited.ncol());
  int j=0;
  for(std::set<int>::iterator index_it=indices.begin();index_it!=indices.end();++index_it){
    temp_mat(j,_)=splited(*index_it,_);
    j++;
  }
  output[it->first]=temp_mat;
 }
 return wrap(output);
}
```

But this implementation is performing much worse than the implementation for vectors. Is there a way to improve this implementation? Or am I missing something fundamental?

I over came these problem by using the Function object in C++. For example

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
List splitR(NumericMatrix x,NumericVector y){
 Function sp("split");
 return sp(x,y);

}
```

even this function have a slight performance difference with the native split. please explain the performance difference between the native functions and function objects?

Comment: _Is there a way to improve this implementation?_  Of course there is, and programming can be hard and challenging.  You are probably making too many temporary copies but I am unfortunately too short of free time to debug this for you. Maybe have a look at [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=dplyr) as well as its sources as it was designed for this (and related) tasks.

Comment: Generally, moving between R and C++ objects should be the first and last things you do. If you need something that grows efficiently, use a `std::vector` -- e.g. fill a `std::vector<double>`, then convert that to a `NumericVector` once you're done with it.

Comment: @KevinUshey Thank you. I will try that and post the results here.

Comment: making use of stl vector instead of NumericVector made the splitVecCpp by 25 times.

Comment: Yes, you don't want to do things like `.push_back()` on Rcpp objects. Due to their `SEXP` nature and fixed size, it will entail a full copy *each time*.